# Best advice for fixing spl-token in production

Tags: spl-token, solana-cli, spl-token-program, spl-associated-token-account, spl-token-cli

After creating and minting an spl-token, I moved all assets to a new wallet and authorized mint for metadata changes, i assumed wrong. Then ran the close command on the original minting wallet.

My issue is that I cannot find a way to close or freeze mint, nor can i remove authority or assign any authorities.

My 2 questions;
From a feasibility, safety and future productivity context.

1. Do I burn and start over? There's about 130 or so wallets with them, no sure that matters.
2. Am I able to fix this via a command i've not found wrap the old token into the new token22?

Not a developer by day, more a hack apologies in advance if wrong format or subject.

Comment: Can you add some more information here?  You should be able to change authorities on the mint by using the CLI, ie `spl-token authorize <MINT_ID> mint <NEW_AUTHORITY>`, assuming that you can sign for the current authority, which you can check using `spl-token display <MINT_ID>`